# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter

Need help to solve this problem, i am trying to learn flutter and got stuck when run to test apk. it just show error Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'. i tried but i had no luck
here is my code

```
class Login {
  final String email;
  final String password;

  Login(this.email,this.password);

  Future<bool> getData(BuildContext context) async {
    bool isSuccessed;
    int id;
    int rule;
    String image;


Response response = await get(InfixApi.login(email, password));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map;
  isSuccessed = user['success'];
  id = user['data']['user']['id'];
  rule = user['data']['user']['role_id'];
  image = user['data']['userDetails']['staff_photo'];

  if (isSuccessed) {
    saveBooleanValue('isLogged', isSuccessed);
    saveStringValue('email', email);
    saveStringValue('password', password);
    saveStringValue('id','$id');
    saveStringValue('rule', '$rule');
    saveStringValue('image', '$image');
    saveStringValue('lang', 'en');
    AppFunction.getFunctions(context,rule.toString());
  }

}
return isSuccessed;


 }



 Future<bool> saveBooleanValue(String key ,bool value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.setBool(key, value);
  }

  Future<bool> saveStringValue(String key ,String value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.setString(key, value);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue comes because you are trying to store id and rule that comes as a string on an int variable, try to replace these two lines:

```
id = user['data']['user']['id'];
rule = user['data']['user']['role_id'];

id = int.parse(user['data']['user']['id']);
rule = int.parse(user['data']['user']['role_id']);
```

Hope it helps